# Showing results on html using form en Ajax (OnChange)

Tags: php, ajax, forms

**This question is SOLVED - solution is on the bottom of the question.**

Let's say I have this form:

```
<form id="form1" action="" method="POST">
<select name="cars">
<option value="">Choose a car</option>
<option value="Ferrari">Ferrari</option>
<option value="Lamborghini">Lamborghini</option>
</select>
<select name="colors">
<option value="">Choose a color</option>
<option value="Green">Green</option>
<option value="Red">Red</option>
</select>
```

**Php**:

```
$cars = $_POST['cars'];
$colors = $_POST['colors'];
echo "Car: ".$cars." - Color: ".$colors."";
```

**Ajax**:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$('select[name="colors"]').on('change', function(){
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "phpfile.php",
data: $("#form1").serialize(),
success: function(data){
$('#target1').html(data);
}
});
return false;
})
</script>
```

I want to show on html the results:

```
<div id="target1"></div>
```

I want to show the results when I choose the color (The 2nd dropdown):

```
onchange="this.form.submit()"
```

**IT IS DONE:)**

I used this code and it I am getting what I want:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$("#colorID").on("change", function() {
var $form = $("#form1");
var method = $form.attr("method") ? $form.attr("method").toUpperCase() : "GET";
$.ajax({
url: 'phpfile.php',
data: $form.serialize(),
type: method,
success: function(data){
$('#target1').html(data);
}
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please tell us what have you tried till now.

Comment: Do you want to show the result on clicking any button?

Comment: @AnkiiG No. I want it "onchange" by the 2nd dropdown. First I choose the car (Happend nothing) then the results shows when I choose the color

Comment: put the form submit in color dropdown on change

Comment: @Pupil I tried since yesterday more than 20 different Ajax codes, but no luck. I don't know anymore what I have to do.

Comment: Hey, please post the code here. You will surely get some help on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Technically you dont need ajax to get what your asking for but heres jQuery ajax example:

Change your HTML to:

```
<select name="colors" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <option value="">Choose a color</option>
    <option value="Green">Green</option>
    <option value="Red">Red</option>
</select>

$( "#form1" ).submit(function( event ) {

 event.preventDeafault();

 alert('form submitted');

     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<YOUR PHP FILE PATH>",
        data: $("#form1").serialize(),
        success: function(data){
            alert('ajax success');
            $('#target1').html(data);
        }else{
            alert('ajax error');
        }

    });

  return false;

})
```

In your PHP:

```
print_r($_POST);
$car = $_POST['car'];
$color = $_POST['color'];
echo "<p>Car: ".$car." - Color: ".$color."</p>";
```

This is untested - I've just typed it out on my phone during my lunch break!

To debug the php add this line ( to unsure the post worked):

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Use your browser developer tools to debug your AJAX and JS

I've add alerts to help you debug - you can remove these when its working

Comment: Hi Jason, Thanks. I did (See update), but nothing shows and nothing happend. Do I have to change something?

Comment: I've updated my answer - also think i missed a closing bracket

Comment: Developer tools are your friend - use them!

Comment: You need to add event.preventDeafault();  to prevent standard form submission - updated answer